# How to calculate Australian Financial Year from a date column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, type-conversion

I have a table called Sales with a date column called SaleDate. How can I write a SQL query that shows the **Australian** financial year in addition to the other columns?

More details:

- I use Microsoft SQL Server
- The Australian financial year starts on 1 July and ends the next year on 30 June.

  - Example 1: 10 June 2019 is FY 2019
  - Example 2: 5 July 2019 is FY 2020

Comment: Which dbms are you using? When it comes to date/time, many products have their own functions.

Comment: Define Australian financial year.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

For Microsoft SQL Server, the following query will show a new column called `FY`, which represents the **Australian** financial year.

```
SELECT
    year(dateadd(MONTH, 6, SaleDate)) AS FY,
    SaleDate,
    Item
FROM Sales
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell OP and the rest of us which dbms this is for.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I updated the answer.